# Como retornar Json(obj) en NET C# WebApi VISUAL STUDIO 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api, webapi, net

estoy tratando de retornar un Json en un WEB API en NET c# en visual studio 2017, y tengo el siguiente código en mi controlador

BuscarSolucionesController.cs

```
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/v1/soluciones/buscar")]
            public JsonResult<ResponseMenu> Menu_Items([FromBody]Soluciones request)
            {
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CadenaConnectionBD1());
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                ResponseMenu obj = new ResponseMenu();
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                JsonArray objarr = new JsonArray();
                string json = "";
                //string reemplazo = "";
                try
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_HD_buscar_solucion";
                    command.Connection = cnn;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@token", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Token;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = request.Status;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_d", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_d;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_h", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_h;
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            obj.ResponseCode = "OK";//Convert.ToString(reader["ResponseCode"]);
                            obj.Message = "ConsultaGenerada";//Convert.ToString(reader["Message"]);
                            obj.Activo = 1;// Convert.ToInt32(reader["Activo"]);

                            json = Convert.ToString(reader["Acceso"]);
                            dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                            JArray jmenu = new JArray();
                            jmenu = response;

                            obj.data = response;
                        }
                        cnn.Close();
                    }

                    

                    return Json(obj);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    obj.ResponseCode = ex.HResult.ToString(); ;
                    obj.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
                    obj.Activo = 99;
                    obj.data = new JArray();
                    return Json(obj);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
```

el problema está en que tengo que retornar un Modelo creado en mi carpeta Models llamado ResponseMenu, pero me da error en el método Json(obj), ya que me dice que no es posible convertir implicitamente de System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult a System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<Api.Models.ResponseMenu>

como puedo solucionarlo para que no me de error y me retorne en json los atributos definidos en el modelo?

Gracias por la ayuda.

ResponseMenu.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LIONAPI.Models
{
    public class ResponseMenu
    {
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int Activo { get; set; }
        public JArray data { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public ActionResult<List<ResponseMenu>> Menu_Items([FromBody] Soluciones request)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CadenaConnectionBD1());
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            List<ResponseMenu> lstobj = new < ResponseMenu > ();
            ResponseMenu obj = new ResponseMenu();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            JsonArray objarr = new JsonArray();
            string json = "";
            //string reemplazo = "";
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_HD_buscar_solucion";
                command.Connection = cnn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@token", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Token;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = request.Status;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_d", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_d;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_h", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_h;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        obj.ResponseCode = "OK";//Convert.ToString(reader["ResponseCode"]);
                        obj.Message = "ConsultaGenerada";//Convert.ToString(reader["Message"]);
                        obj.Activo = 1;// Convert.ToInt32(reader["Activo"]);

                        json = Convert.ToString(reader["Acceso"]);
                        JArray response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JArray;

                        obj.data = response;
                        lstobj.Add(obj);
                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }



                return Json(lstobj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj.ResponseCode = ex.HResult.ToString(); ;
                obj.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
                obj.Activo = 99;
                obj.data = new JArray();
                return Json(obj);
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }


        public class ResponseMenu
        {
            public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public int Activo { get; set; }
            public JArray data { get; set; }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola para deserializar debes de decir a que objeto vas a mapear, de lo contrario devuelves tal cual.

```
  public ActionResult<ResponseMenu> Menu_Items([FromBody] Soluciones request)
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        ResponseMenu obj = new ResponseMenu();
        string json = "";
        //string reemplazo = "";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CadenaConnectionBD1()))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_HD_buscar_solucion";
                command.Connection = cnn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@token", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Token;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = request.Status;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_d", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_d;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fecha_h", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = request.Fecha_h;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        obj.ResponseCode = "OK";//Convert.ToString(reader["ResponseCode"]);
                        obj.Message = "ConsultaGenerada";//Convert.ToString(reader["Message"]);
                        obj.Activo = 1;// Convert.ToInt32(reader["Activo"]);
                        obj.data = Convert.ToString(reader["Acceso"]);
                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }

            }

            return Ok(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.ResponseCode = ex.HResult.ToString(); ;
            obj.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
            obj.Activo = 99;
            return BadRequest(obj);
        }
    }


    public class ResponseMenu
    {
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int Activo { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }


    }
```